# What is the difference between equals "=" and colon ":" signs in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a `onSubmit()` method in Vuejs. Couldn't figure what is the difference between equal `=` and colon  `:` sign. Here is the following cod

```
methods:{
   onSubmit(){
     let product= {
     name: this.name,
     review: this.review,
     rating: this.rating
      },
    this.name=null,
    this.review=null,
    this.rating=null       
  }
}
```

In the above function I am storing values in object called `product`, after storing values I am assigning `null` values to data variables.

Why we are passing values to `product` object using `:` and to data object using `=` sign?

Comment: Yes they are already null.

Comment: In that case, manually setting them back to null is a bit pointless; they are already null. (I accidentally deleted my previous comment)

Comment: This isn't specific to Vue. This applies to javascript in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
     name: this.name,
     review: this.review,
     rating: this.rating
}
```

This creates an object, which is a data structure.

```
let product = {}
```

Here you are assigning the object (data structure) to a variable.

Comment: It may be helpful to explain the difference between object key/value mapping (:), and property value assignment (=)

Comment: I got the point above key value pair mapping, and why we are assigning the null values using equal sign?

Comment: Because that's how you assign values to variables. `this.name` is a variable, and you have to use the assignment operator to modify that variable